# Trigger a timer from parent component in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

How to correctly trigger a method in a child component from its parent in Vue 3. Something other than Event Bus.

Here's the timer trigger method:

```
methods: {
    startTimer: function () {
      this.timer = setInterval(() => this.countdown(), 1000);   
    },
```

I need to set it off by pressing a button in parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the parent component add a ref to the child one and trigger that method using that ref :

```
<Child ref="childRef" />
```

and trigger it somewhere like :

```
 this.$refs.childRef.startTimer()
```